# Conditional selection of a single record from multiple similar records in sqlite3 database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android application which uses Sqlite3 database for storage.

Recently i cam across a problem where i need to select a row from multiple similar rows based on the condition i have on a specific column.

Just to be more specific...

**Source data:**

```
_id | code | language | data

 1  | 1    | English  | aaa

 2  | 1    | French   | bbb

 3  | 1    | Spanish  | ccc

 4  | 1    | Portuguse| ddd

 5  | 2    | English  | eee

 6  | 2    | French   | fff

 7  | 3    | English  | ggg

 8  | 4    | French   | hhh
```

Multiple entries in database can have same code value and different language values.

My conditions are as follows:

1. I should have at least one record of each code value.
2. I have to search based on the language i want. Suppose if i give language as Spanish, i should get all the records that are in Spanish.
3. If any code entry that doesn't have the given language i have given , then i should get the English entry of that code.
4. If any of the code entry has only one record with one language, then i should get that record irrespective of the language i have given.

**My expected result from the above table:**

If i give language as Spanish :-

```
3  | 1    | Spanish  | ccc

5  | 2    | English  | eee

7  | 3    | English  | ggg

8  | 4    | French   | hhh
```

1. I should have 1,2,3,4 code values.
2. With language Spanish with code 1 i have a record for Spanish, So it should come.
3. With language Spanish with code 2 i have no record for Spanish, So record with code 2 and language English should be selected.
4. Code 3 & 4 records have only one entry , so those records should come.

I have searched a lot on the web on how to manipulate these kind of conditions on similar rows, but I could not get the answer. Can some one help me out with a query for the expected result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to accomplish it in one monster query, here is one approach based on outer joining several subqueries.  **Assumptions: `(code, language)` is a unique key; all columns are `NOT NULL`.**

---

First, rule 1 says that each code needs to be represented in the final result.  Let `all_codes` be a subquery that provides each unique code:

```
(select code 
   from my_table 
  group by code) all_codes
```

Next, rule 2 says that any rows with the desired language need to be present.  Let `matches` be the subquery that provides these rows:

```
(select _id, code, language, data 
   from my_table 
  where language = ?) matches
```

Next, rule 3 says that in the absence of the desired language, fall back to English.  Let `en_fallbacks` be the subquery that provides these rows:

```
(select _id, code, language, data 
   from my_table 
  where language = 'English') en_fallbacks
```

Rule 4 says that any singleton record for a particular code should be present in the result.  Let `singletons` be the subquery that provides these rows:

```
(select MIN(_id) as _id, code, MIN(language) as language, MIN(data) as data 
   from my_table 
  group by code 
 having (MIN(_id) = MAX(_id))) singletons
```

---

Finally, left join them together in order on the shared `code` column and use `COALESCE` to get the column values you need:

```
select all_codes.code,
       COALESCE(matches._id, en_fallbacks._id, singletons._id) as _id,
       COALESCE(matches.language, en_fallbacks.language, singletons.language) as language,
       COALESCE(matches.data, en_fallbacks.data, singletons.data) as data
  from (...) all_codes
       left outer join (...) matches on (all_codes.code = matches.code)
       left outer join (...) en_fallbacks on (all_codes.code = en_fallbacks.code)
       left outer join (...) singletons on (all_codes.code = singletons.code)
```

**Caution:** I have not tested these queries for correctness or performance.